# how to have regex stop searching for A after a max number of matching of B

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to search a keyword A in a group of lines with Python re library. The number of lines in a group is in a range of 3 to 5. Each line is enclosed by "
" and "". The keyword A may or may not appear in the group. If it doesn't, I want it to get a None to me. A sample of the text looks like:

```
<BR>GROUP #1</BR>
<BR>arbitrary characters 1</BR>
<BR>arbitrary characters 2</BR>
<BR>arbitrary characters 3</BR>
<BR>GROUP #2</BR>
<BR>arbitrary characters 4</BR>
<BR>arbitrary characters 5</BR>
<BR>KEYWORD_A_2</BR>
<BR>Group #3</BR>
<BR>arbitrary characters 6</BR>
<BR>arbitrary characters 7</BR>
<BR>arbitrary characters 8</BR>
<BR>KEYWORD_A_3</BR>
....
```

(Note: the uppercase characters may be keywords and should appear exactly same it the original text.)

My first attempt, `'<BR>Group #(\d+)</BR>.*?<BR>Keyword_A_(\d+)</BR>'` obviously may cross the border of the groups and get a match of (1, 2), instead of (1, None) as I wished.

My next attempt is `'<BR>Group #(\d+)</BR>(?:<BR>.*?</BR>){,3}<BR>Keyword_A_(\d+)</BR>'`, to limit the 
.. pairs to be 3. But that will be a greedy match so that 'KEYWORD_A_3' is matched and (1, 3) is returned.

So, in summary, I am trying to have regex to find 'KEYWORD_A_(\d+)' after maximum of 5 lines after a match of 'GROUP #(\d+)'. If no match beyond 5 lines, just stop searching, return None, and set the regex's current position at the end of match of 'GROUP #(\d+)', so I can start to search in next group.

Is that possible with re library of Python? Thanks for any helps.

Comment: Try `<BR>Group\s+#(\d+)</BR>((?:(?!<BR>Group\s+#\d).)*?)<BR>Keyword_A_(\d+)</BR>`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/IBREum/1). In Python, the regex must be compiled with `re.I | re.S` flags.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for your response and demo. That works for the scenario that <BR>Group\s+#\d+ delimits the two groups. It is a very smart walk around.

What if the first line of each group is not so predictable and I have to count the number of lines without 'KEYWORD_A_\d+'? Thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Sorry I didn't make myself clear enough. I need to search for A, which is "KEYWORD_A_(\d+)" within a certain amount of match of B, which is "</BR>". Can I implement that in regex? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, I think you wanted `<BR>Group\s+#(\d+)</BR>(?:\n<BR>.*</BR>){0,5}\n<BR>Keyword_A_(\d+)</BR>`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ph7nNn/1). `{0,5}` means 0 to 5, as many as possible. You might actually want to use  a lazy variant, `{0,5}?`. You may  adjust the numeric values as you need.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. You gave me a good hint to add a '\n' between each line. I forgot to mention in my original post that actually there is *NO* '\n' between each <BR>...</BR> line, i.e. all these lines are actually written in one concatenated line in my project. That might be the reason why my second attempt in the original post didn't work. Like in demo:<https://regex101.com/r/H7KlPr/3/>, it matches Group#1 with Keyword_A_2. But as you suggested, if with '\n', your solution works pretty well, although I could not figured out why the difference. Can you give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: You used `.*?` that matches any text, including the pattern starting pattern, so it match match across blocks.

Comment: But you are using .*, which I understand it is a greedy searching method to match as many characters as possible. How could that make the difference? If I use your solution, removing the '\n', against my one-line string, it still fails, like <https://regex101.com/r/H7KlPr/4/>. So I am still wondering why the '\n' could be the killer.

Comment: Ok, I thought of another regex. Use `[^<]*` instead of `.*`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/H7KlPr/5).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. You are the hero. Saved my project. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I updated the question [here](https://regex101.com/r/H7KlPr/7). The problem is more tricky than I had thought. Can you pls take a look? Thanks~

Comment: You really should start thinking about discarding regex and writing a simple parser. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ev7CEp/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'<BR>Group\s+#(\d+)</BR>((?:(?!<BR>Group\s+#\d).)*?)<BR>Keyword_A_(\d+)</BR>', text, re.DOTALL)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IBREum/1)

**Details**

- `<BR>Group` - a literal `<BR>Group` string
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `#` - a `#` char
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits
- `</BR>` - a substring
- `((?:(?!<BR>Group\s+#\d).)*?)` - Capturing group 2: any char, 0 or more but as few as possible occurrences that does not start a `<BR>Group\s+#\d` pattern
- `<BR>Keyword_A_`  - a literal substring
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 3: one or more digits
- `</BR>` - a substring